# Execute Events in an Infinite Loop

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, infinite-loop

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();   //get which button is clicked

        if(src.equals(GO))     //if GO button is clicked
        {
            try {
                runHack();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(src.equals(STOP))   //if STOP button is clicked
        {
            //do nothing
            FeedBack.setText(null);
            FeedBack.setText("Stopped");

        }
    }
```

I have a program where when you click on a button `GO`, it will execute a method called `runHack();`

```
 private void runHack() throws AWTException 
 {
    FeedBack.setText(null);
    FeedBack.setText("Running(This doesn't print out)");

   while(true)//infinite loop
   {
        FeedBack.setText("This doesn't print out");
   }
}
```

`runHack()` is method that runs an infinite loop. When I click on the GO button, the program freezes while executing the `runHack()` method. The String `"Running"` doesn't displayed on the `JLabel FeedBack`.

My question is how do you make events still available when the program is in the infinite loop? I want it so that when I press on the STOP button, the program exits out of the infinite loop. Also, I want the `JLabel FeedBack` to work inside the loop.

Comment: You basically can't run Swing with an infinite loop.  It can't work.

Comment: you need to run in a thread

Comment: You should run the runHack() method inside a new Thread in order to allow the UIThread to continue its work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with threads. Can you give me an example?

Comment: you should look at swing worker

Comment: `"I'm not familiar with threads. Can you give me an example?"` -- man, you're asking a very broad question, one that would require a full tutorial to answer. And in fact that's your answer -- read a full tutorial on the subject. Start here: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Another option is to not use threading directly, but to instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: I believe I found a solution using threads on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327101/java-swing-cancelling-an-infinite-loop

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't blindly use that code, since if you do, you will likely be making swing calls off of the Swing event thread, a dangerous thing to do. Read the tutorial links.

Comment: why do you think you need an infinite loop. just set the label when you hit the button?  no need to hang around

Comment: I want to use that label to print out some content that I'll be computing in that infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

you need run this infine toop inside of a new thread .this is how to do using timer .swing timer runs in separate thread.set delay to zero.so it's act as a while(true) loop.
in your code you are blocking `EDT` because of long lasting task(infinite loop) .the changes you made to textfield not get update because `EDT` is blocked.

you need to `swing timer` not java.util.Timer

```
import import javax.swing.Timer;
```

declare timer

```
Timer t;//global declaration;
```

initialize //

```
 t=new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        FeedBack.setText("This doesn't print out");
    }
});
```

when button click//

```
 JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();   //get which button is clicked

    if(src.equals(GO))     //if GO button is clicked
    {
        try {
            t.start();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(src.equals(STOP))   //if STOP button is clicked
    {
        //do nothing
        t.stop();
        FeedBack.setText(null);
        FeedBack.setText("Stopped");

    }
```

updating...

a complete example

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class example extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    Timer t;
    private final JTextField FeedBack;
    private JButton go;
    private JButton stop;
    int i=0;

    public example() {
         FeedBack=new JTextField("initial text");
         go=new JButton("go");
         stop=new JButton("stop");
           go.addActionListener(this);
           stop.addActionListener(this);

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        this.add(go);
        this.add(stop);
        this.add(FeedBack);
        this.setVisible(true);

        t = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FeedBack.setText(i+"");
                i++;
            }
        });

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();
        System.out.println(src);
        if (src==go) //if GO button is clicked
        {               
            t.start();
        }
        if (src==stop) //if STOP button is clicked
        {
            //stop timer
            t.stop();
            //FeedBack.setText(null);
            FeedBack.setText("Stopped");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example f = new example();
    }
}
```

output>>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm not sure why, but this case doesn't seem to work. The `FeedBack`label only displays `Hello World`.

Comment: @user123206 try to run the class i have posted. what is robot.delay??

Comment: if you can post your complete code anywhere not here  ( http://pastebin.com/archive/java ) .then i can check it

Comment: `Robot robot = new Robot();`  `robot.delay(3000)` delays the program by 3 seconds.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UEmFd7M9
I'm trying to make a robot to control my computer. lol

Comment: Sure. I might have a few `robot.delay(3000);` statements in the infinite loop.

Comment: @user123206 is it you expect?

Comment: I wanted to use `robot.delay(5000);` to delay the time between each task done by the robot.

Comment: `robot.delay(3000); FeedBack.setText(null); FeedBack.setText("Run"); ; robot.delay(3000); FeedBack.setText(null); FeedBack.setText("Hello World");`

For this code, only `Hello World` was displayed.

Comment: @user123206 i still don't know why you need this robot .any way understand this.if you wait 3 seconds + 3 seconds time inside timer you need to change timer delay to 6000 or more than 6000.example t = new Timer(6000, new ActionListener()

Comment: It seems like the delaying part works, even if it's  `t = new Timer(0, new ActionListener())`. The JLabel seems to be the problem. My robot delays between tasks, but the label isn't displaying. Also the STOP button doesn't really work while it's running. lol

Comment: So for now, I'm displaying text using `System.out.println();` instead of the label, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run(){
   runHack();
 }
}).start();
```

Just take in account that there are better ways to spawn new Threads like using an Executor. Like someone commented, Threads is a broad topic, you should read the documentation.

[EDIT]
Like @Hovercraft Full Of Eels said is not Thread safe calling in a new Thread modifications of the UI.

Comment: Please fix this answer, since with your code he is calling `setText(...)` on a Swing component **off** of the Swing event thread, not a good or nice thing to recommend to a newbie.